# Mock/Reality consistency : unit test or integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-tests

In a golang project, I have mocked external services. But in order to check that mocked services has the same behaviour as real services, I have done some common testing on the interface with both mock and real, so with real credentials.

Let's say that I have :

```
repositories/serviceA/mock/mock.go
repositories/serviceA/mock/mock_test.go
repositories/serviceA/live/live.go
repositories/serviceA/live/live_test.go
repositories/serviceA/tests/tests.go
```

In each `*_test.go` i have imported tests from `repositories/serviceA/tests/tests.go`. However, in `live_test.go`, I have to give `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET` in order to test against the real API of the service I am mocking.

In `repositories/serviceA/tests/tests.go`, you can find tests like

```
func TestRead(s ServiceInterface)
func TestWrite(s ServiceInterface)
....
```

In `repositories/serviceA/mock/mock_test.go`, I would have:

```
func TestReadMock() {
    m := NewMock()
    tests.TestRead(m)
}
```

In `repositories/serviceA/live/live_test.go`, I would have:

```
func TestReadLive() {
    l := NewLive(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    tests.TestRead(l)
}
```

My question is, should I integrate those tests with unit tests (as done in example) as they test each function of mock/real structs or with integration tests as they use credentials and test with real services ? It's bugging me because it's running with other mock tests but it is clearly unit testing.

Thanks for the insight ! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "in order to check that mocked services has the same behaviour as real services" - when you mock something, you're doing it in order to test the behavior *of the thing that uses the mock*. The mock is just there to supply an expected canned (or preconfigured) answer needed for *that specific test* in isolation, you don't care about anything else - a mock shouldn't replicate all of the behaviors of a real service. You're not interested in the behavior of the mock or the service itself (beyond what's needed to satisfy the abstract interface in the context of that particular test case).

Comment: E.g., suppose you call a remote 3rd party service and ask it to return all employees of a certain department, and the service returns, among other results, an employee of a *different* department (and you can tell from the data returned); suppose this is due to a bug someone introduced in the last update. That is not the specified/expected behavior of the service. Yet you can and should have a test case for this ("service returns wrong data"), involving a lightweight mock instance that is configured to only return an example dataset that's wrong in this particular way, and does nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! So that means that when there is an update for the 3rd party service, you have to check every mock in every test to be sure that it is coherent with updates ?